# sql: order by clause returns results which are sub sorted lists

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

i am trying to run a query which looks like this:

```
select term,X2_T_SI 
from termtoclassscienceraj 
where R_T_SI>1 and X2_T_SI>9 order by X2_T_SI
```

on a table with structure

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TERM     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| T_SI     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| T_XSI    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| XT_SI    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| XT_XSI   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| E_T_SI   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| E_T_XSI  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| E_XT_SI  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| E_XT_XSI | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| X2_T_SI  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| R_T_SI   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

but this results in an output in which have is sub parts sorted.
e.g. if 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9 are the values on which the sort is to run the out put have them as 2,3,4,| 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,| 2, 3, 4
note | mark has been used to just show the problem in result

Comment: Post some input data with desired result

Comment: Why do you store comma separated integers in a `varchar`-column? Create another table that is linked to this table via foreign-key.

Comment: can you please show exact output from the table ..

Comment: Watch out spaces. You have varchar datatype and expected output as numbers.

Comment: To make a guess, `select term,CONCAT(X2_T_SI,'|') from..`